# Node js - ftp-srv - Simple ftp Server Example needed

Tags: javascript, node.js

The last days I'm trying to get a simple ftp-server running in NodeJS.

I found a package named "ftp-srv" with some documentation here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ftp-srv

Inspire by the code-snipptes there I wrote a small script:

```
const FtpSrv = require ( 'ftp-srv' );

const hostname = '0.0.0.0';
const port = 1111

const ftpServer = new FtpSrv ( 'ftp://' + hostname + ':' + port,
{ anonymous: true, greeting : [ "Hello Jong", "Wie gehts?" ] } );

ftpServer.on ( 'login', ( data, resolve, reject ) =>
{
  console.log ( 'data: '    + data );
  console.log ( 'resolve: ' + resolve );
  console.log ( 'reject: '  + reject );

});

ftpServer.on ( 'client-error', (connection, context, error) =>
{
  console.log ( 'connection: ' +  connection );
  console.log ( 'context: '    +  context );
  console.log ( 'error: '      +  error );
});


ftpServer.listen()
.then(() =>
{
  console.log ( `Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/` );
});
```

I can start the Script with "node ftpserver.js" and it runs without a Problem.
If I connect with a FTP-Client Software it seems to connect, but waits for the "Welcome Message" and hangs at that point.

I provided the "greeting"-Variable but that text is not send to the client.

I searched a lot in google but couldnt find any working Examples for "ftp-srv".

I think the point where I have to fill in some code is here:

```
ftpServer.on ( 'login', ( data, resolve, reject ) =>
{
  // HERE
});
```

It would help me a lot if anyone could provide some Example-code to get a working client connection and to overcome the greeting message.

--- Edit ---

The Advice from jcaron helped a lot, Im one step further now. These are my changes:

```
[...]
ftpServer.on ( 'login', ( data, resolve, reject ) =>
{
  resolve ( { root: '/home/peter/apps/ftpfiles' } );
});
[...]
```

When I connect with a client now, the client tries to read the remote directory. After 3 tries the client get a timeout.

It seems like the client cant access the directory '/home/peter/apps/ftpfiles'. I can say that it exists and has read/write permissions by the user which I start my "ftpserver.js"-Script.

I tried some things with a fs-object instead of root:[dir], but always see the same behaviour.

Can anyone help?

--- Edit ---

In addition simply changed

```
const hostname = '0.0.0.0';
#to local address:
const hostname = '192.x.y.z';
```

and it worked for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you receive the `login` event, you need to call either `resolve` or `reject` based on what you decided what the result of the authentication.

If you consider the login info is correct, call `resolve`, passing it an object with the relevant details, for instance:

```
resolve({root: '/path/to/files/accessible/via/ftp'})
```

Also note that if you are testing locally on a private network, you should probably use you local IP or `127.0.0.1` as the hostname. `0.0.0.0` makes it use the external IP address.

Comment: That helped a lot, thank you very much! Now I hang at the Client not getting the directory-listing. I updated my post.

Comment: Is the client on the same computer as the server, or on the same LAN? Change the `0.0.0.0` address to `127.0.0.1` in the first case or the actual local IP in either case.

Comment: I already changed to 127.0.0.1. forgot to mention. But as I changed to the local address it worked :-)). Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is when you receive an permisson denied ?

Comment: @Alex this should probably be a new question. Depends a lot on where exactly you get the permission denied. If it’s during set up of the connection, it is most likely because you are trying to listen on a privileged port (port < 1024) and you are not root.