# how to set username and password of ftp-srv in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, ftp-server

I'm using [ftp-srv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ftp-srv) package to create an ftp-server.

Here is my code:

```
const FtpSvr = require ( 'ftp-srv' );

const hostname = '0.0.0.0';
const port = 5053

const ftpServer = new FtpSvr ({
    url:'ftp://' + hostname + ':' + port ,
    anonymous: false,
    greeting : [ "Hello Jong"]
});

ftpServer.listen()
    .then(() =>
    {
        console.log ( `Server Running at ftp://${hostname}:${port}/` );
    });
```

**I don't know how to set username and password of ftp-users!**

I found an event handler named "login"

```
ftpServer.on('login', ({connection, username, password}, resolve, reject) => { ... });
```

but I couldn't find out, how to use it!   :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference the ftp-srv [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ftp-srv)

```
ftpServer.on('login', ({connection, username, password}, resolve, reject) => { ... });
```

When you receive the login event, you need to call either resolve or reject based on what you decided what the result of the authentication.

If you consider the login info is correct, call resolve, passing it an object with the relevant details, for instance:

```
resolve({root: '/path/to/files/accessible/via/ftp'})
```

Also note that if you are testing locally on a private network, you should probably use you local IP or 127.0.0.1 as the hostname. 0.0.0.0 makes it use the external IP address.

Reference [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46234845/node-js-ftp-srv-simple-ftp-server-example-needed/46235136?noredirect=1#comment115403113_46235136) answer

Like mentioned above you can check **username** and **password** like this
if password and user is right call **resolve** otherwise call **reject**

```
  if(username === "lorem" && password === "ipsum"){
       // call resolve 
       resolve({});
    else{
      // if password and username are incorrectly then call reject
       reject({});
    }
```

Reference this article
https://stackoverrun.com/de/q/12681767

Comment: Thanks. you wrote "If you consider the login info is correct". this is exactly my question? how to consider the login info is correct?

Comment: You can check in resolve if the given username and password is correct

Comment: I will give an example wait

Comment: Thank you Alex. I'll wait for your example.

Comment: I ve updated my answer hope this will help you

Comment: It seems checking the username and password is ok. but when I call resolve({root: './test'}); , on the other side raise an error

Comment: This is the error: an error occurred opening that folder on the ftp server make sure you have permission

Comment: check the permissions of the directory you will open

Comment: try it with something in your home directory there you should have the permissions by default

Comment: Thank you Alex. it didn't work. I create a new question about the permission problem just now